# Let $\theta>0$, find the matrix associated with the identity map, and rotation of basis by angle $-\theta$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\theta>0$, find the matrix associated with the identity map, and rotation of basis by angle $-\theta$.

So it changes basis from $(1, 0), (0, 1)$ to $(\cos\theta, -\sin\theta), (\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$ associated with the identity map.

Then 
$(1, 0)=a_1(\cos\theta, -\sin\theta)+a_2(\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$
$(0, 1)=b_1(\cos\theta, -\sin\theta)+b_2(\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$
$a_1=\cos\theta, a_2=\sin\theta, b_1=-\sin\theta, b_2=\cos\theta$
i.e. the matrix is \begin{equation*}
A_{m,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
But the solution says it's
\begin{equation*}
A_{m,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Where I did wrong?

Comment: What are supposed to be the bases   for the domain and for the codomain?

Comment: @Bernard this question is on page 93 of Serge Lang's linear algebra. It did not say very clear, I think. It only says, in general, let $\theta>0$, what is the matrix associated with the identity map, and rotation of basis by angle $−\theta$.

Comment: But we need  to know whether the rotated basis is for the domain or for the codomain. Without  this information, how can it be answered?